# facing error : - TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of null

Tags: javascript, express

my post timeline system seems failing with this error the code for the same is :

1.

```
const router = require("express").Router();

const postModel = require("../models/post");
const userModel = require("../models/user");

// catch timeline posts
router.get("/timeline/all", async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const currentUser = await userModel.findById(req.body.userId);
      const userPosts = await postModel.find({ userId: currentUser._id });
      const friendPosts = await Promise.all(
        currentUser.followings.map((friendId) => {
          return Post.find({ userId: friendId });
        })
      );
      res.json(userPosts.concat(...friendPosts))
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
  });

module.exports = router;
```

and for my schema here :
1 USER SCHEMA

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
        min: 3,
        max: 20,
        unique: true
    },

    useremail: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        max: 50,
        unique: true,
    },

    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 6
    },

    profilePicture: {
        type: String,
        default: ""
    },

    coverPicture: {
        type: String,
        default: ""
    },

    followers: {
        type: Array,
        default: []
    },

    following: {
        type: Array,
        default: []
    },

    isAdmin: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },

    description: {
        type: String,
        max: 50
    },

    from: {
        type: String,
        max: 50
    },

    relationship: {
        type: Number,
        enum: [1, 2, 3]
    },
},
    { timestamps: true }
);

// exporting for use in other files
module.exports = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);
```

2 POST SCHEMA

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    userId: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    description: {
        type: String,
        max: 500
    },

    img: {
        type: String
    },

    likes: {
        type: Array,
        default: []
    },
},
    { timestamps: true }
);

// exporting for use in other files
module.exports = mongoose.model("post", postSchema);
```

I know noone would like such a post and moreover this is spoonfeed,
its just me being a stupid who cant figure out something silly,
Thanks for your help and time really appreciate u ppls effort
once again sry for such a post but thanks for reviewing

Comment: The find function can return null if no user was found, you have to check for it.
this line here `const currentUser = await userModel.findById(req.body.userId);` can set currentUser to null. I assume that either you are sending data in the wrong format, looking for an id that does not exist or simply you are not parsing the incoming request body data properly. Are you sure `req.body.userId` has data in it?

Comment: that shouldnt be the case i suppose but i am new so maybe i am wrong but i do have data in MongoDB : https://imgur.com/kj80GQH